# Scrapy LinkExtractor - restrict_paths - exclude tags

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

When extracting links from a webpage, I want to get all links except those inside the header. To not extract links from the header, I've created an XPath which matches everything except header or footer:

```
*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@id,"header") or contains(@class,"header") or header or contains(@id,"footer") or contains(@class,"footer") or footer])]
```

The problem is that when I put as a `restricted_paths` argument, it doesn't work correctly. I get even more links than I get without specifying `restricted_paths` argument.

```
LinkExtractor(allow_domains=netloc).extract()
```

returns 120 links.

```
LinkExtractor(allow_domains=netloc, restrict_xpaths=["""//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@id,"header") or contains(@class,"header") or header or contains(@id,"footer") or contains(@class,"footer") or footer])]"""]).extract_links(response)
```

returns 199 links including those inside header (`<div id="header"> .... </div>`)

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Just use simple for loop, `for link in response.xpath('//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@id,"header") or contains(@class,"header") or header or contains(@id,"footer") or contains(@class,"footer") or footer])]')`